# Do I need a Visa or some kind of permission for a layover/stopover in the USA as a German citizen?

Tags: usa, layovers, esta, stopovers, german-citizens

I booked a flight from Mexico to Germany with a 3 hour layover in the USA (Atlanta).

Do I need some kind of Visa or permission for this layover?

Unfortunately I can only find contradictory information about this. Some sources say I need a so called ESTA from [here](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/), and others say I don't need anything. What do I really need?

Comment: You do need an ESTA. The confusion might stem from the fact than an ESTA is not a visa so it's also correct to write that you don't need a visa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are qualified for the [Visa Waiver Program](http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/visit/visa-waiver-program.html), so you don't need any Visa (Transit Visa) for this layover, but you will definitely need an [ESTA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_System_for_Travel_Authorization) for your layover and taking connecting flight from US. ESTA is mandatory even for people from countries participating is visa waiver program.

Refer this question from Yahoo answer for clarification: [Do i need USA visa for flight stopover?](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20111211091527AA3WCZa)

ESTA adds a requirement for pre-authorization to the existing Visa Waiver Program. ESTA is not needed when arriving by land from Canada or Mexico (but this is not in your case). Passengers (including babies) without an ESTA may be denied check in, although it is possible to get one while at the departure airport.

Comment: "ESTA is mandatory even for people from countries participating is visa waiver program." In fact, ESTA is *only* for people from countries in the VWP.

Comment: @user102008 moreover, ESTA is only for *people* who are traveling under the visa waiver program.  If you are from a visa waiver country, but are nonetheless traveling to the US on a visa, you will not use ESTA.